# Test to compare 4 proportions in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I would need help in order to perform a proportion comparison between 4 different modalities of one factor.

**Here is an example.**

I would like to compare the proportion of mother-to-child smoking between individuals from 4 different countries.

```
Contry   USA  INDIA  CHINA  ITALIA
Mother   100  2000   1600   200 
Child    25   860    64     10
%        25%  43%    4%     5%
```

So what I would like to compare is then the percentage of smoking child between countries
I firts tought to chi2 test of fit to a uniform distribution law such as:

```
           USA  INDIA  CHINA  ITALIA  
observed   25%  43%    4%     5%    
expected   25%  25%    25%    25%
```

But I know chi2 does work only on numbers and not on proportions, right ?

Does someone have an idea of a test to support that `USA` and `INDIA` have a significantly higher level of smoking childs regarding their mothers compared to `CHINA` and `ITALIA` compared to what is expected if it were homogeneous ?

Thanks a lot for you help and time

Note: keep in mind that it is just a toy data, meaningless without any biological sens, I just want to put a sample example where I would like to compare proportions.